# How to pass a HashMap to a function in Rust

Tags: hashmap, rust

Can anybody explain why following code does not compile?

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn add(mut h: &HashMap<&str, &str>) {
    h.insert("foo", "bar");
}

fn main() {
    let mut h: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
    add(&h);
    println!("{:?}", h.get("foo"));
}
```

This is what rustc tells me

```
hashtest.rs:4:5: 4:6 error: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `*h` as mutable
hashtest.rs:4     h.insert("foo", "bar");
                  ^
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is that you pass a **mutable reference** to a HashMap (i.e. the reference can be changed to point to another `HashMap`), and not a **reference to a mutable** `HashMap` (i.e. the `HashMap` can change).

Here is a correct code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn add(h: &mut HashMap<&str, &str>) {
    h.insert("foo", "bar");
}

fn main() {
    let mut h: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
    add(&mut h);
    println!("{:?}", h.get("foo"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! This really helped